# ¿Cómo podría hacer que un atributo altere su valor dentro de un loop en cada iteración?

Tags: java

En principio declaré estas variables:

int vidaHombre = 100;

int vidaEnemigo = (int) (Math.random() * 101) + 50;

int ataqueHombre = 20;

int ataqueEnemigo = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + 10;

y en el loop la condición es la siguiente:

while ((vidaHombre > 0) ||(vidaEnemigo > 0)) {

int suerte = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

```
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("El felino le lanza sus zarpas al hombre. Intenta esquivarlo");
                
                if (suerte < 5) {
                    System.out.println("¡No lo logra!");
                    System.out.println("¡El felino lo golpea!");
                    System.out.println("Le genera un daño de " + ataqueEnemigo);
                    int resultado = vidaHombre - ataqueEnemigo;
                    System.out.println("Su vida se reduce a " + resultado);
                } else if (suerte > 5) {
                    System.out.println("¡Logra esquivar el ataque!");
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de asignar el valor a una nueva variable 'resultado' , asigna el valor a la variable que te interesa modificar

```
vidaHombre= vidaHombre - ataqueEnemigo
```

Comment: Por cierto tal vez te interese aprovechar el curso gratis de Java que ofrece Oracle por aniversario , expira a finales de abril  te dará algunas bases sobre Programación Orientada a Objetos 

https://education.oracle.com/java-25th-anniversary-discount-redemption

Es una buena oportunidad

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!